Vue3: hot to avoid many v-if conditions for loading the image, based on 10+ states
I have a view where a state dictates the icon to display. There is total of 12 different icons / states. The icon itself is also a .vue component (<template><svg...></svg></template>).
So currently I have icons displayed with 12 v-if blocks (see below). Here's how it looks:
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  state: 's1' | 's2' | 's3' | ... | 's12';
}>();
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <IconA v-if="state === 's1'"/>
    <IconB v-if="state === 's2'"/>
    <IconC v-if="state === 's3'"/>
    <!-- repeat for the rest of them... -->
    <IconL v-if="state === 's12'"/>
  </div>
</template>

And I wonder if there's a more efficient / elegant way to express the same.

Refactor using a loop with v-for.  Only question is is <IconA> a completely different component than <IconB>, or are they just named that way in your question for illustrative purposes?

Use <Component/>: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics#dynamic-components
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  state: 's1' | 's2' | 's3' | ... | 's12';
}>();

const icons = {s1:IconA, s2:IconB, ...};

</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="icons[state]"/>
  </div>
</template>


Lazy loading the icons using defineAsyncComponent (or Lazy in Nuxt) could result in better performance since there would be less to load.
Using v-else-if instead of v-if would also improve performance.
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';

defineProps<{
  state: 's1' | 's2' | 's3' | 's12';
}>();

const IconA = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/IconA'));
const IconB = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/IconB'));
const IconC = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/IconC'));
// repeat
const IconL = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/IconL'));
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <IconA v-if="state === 's1'" />
    <IconB v-else-if="state === 's2'" />
    <IconC v-else-if="state === 's3'" />
    <!-- repeat for the rest of them... -->
    <IconL v-else-if="state === 's12'" />
  </div>
</template>

